# how to get touchscreen coordinates

Tags: raspbian, display, touchscreen

I'm using waveshare 5 inch HDMI touchscreen on my raspberry pi , I need a python code to determine the X,Y coordinates of touched point. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Your touchscreen works just as every other screen. I suppose you also had to connect an USB cable to your Pi. This acts just like a normal mouse. When you touch your screen, that virtual mouse moves to that point and makes a click there.

You can get the position of the mouse with [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) The following code prints the mouse position:

```
import pyautogui
print(pyautogui.position())
```

I hope that helps, otherwise clarify your question or write a comment

Comment: [This link](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD#FAQ) mentions they use GPIO, not USB, for touch events on the 5" screen. Apparently Waveshare's 7" screen does use HID USB.